# Understanding the Direction of Arrows After Distorting a Sphere into a Square

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

I'm watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6-Z0qgYjVjU&list=PLmrgknFb6E37wJs3sd7jlSGSZFFFk4IgL&index=3&t=9m0s) on basic topology and around 9 minutes in they introduce the sphere and how it can be cut along a line from the north to the south pole then distorted into a square, using arrows along the cuts to show how the new boundaries were previously connected. There are two arrows on the sphere, the arrow on top pointing towards the north pole and the one on the bottom towards the south (I suppose both arrows point to both poles on the sphere but my question is about after cutting, at which point I think both poles are truly on opposite ends of the 1-sided surface they live on).

After cutting along this line, these two arrows become four half-arrows which live on the boundary of the square. This makes sense. However, now the all arrows point towards the north pole, as shown below.

[image: the sphere cutting from the video]

I imagine the half-arrows should still point towards their respective poles, which I believe are on opposite sides (top and bottom, as he's showing it) of the square, and I don't understand why this isn't the case.

Just logically, it seems that each point on a cut has to be mapped to at least two points on the new surface, so I think it's possible that my confusion stems from that. Based on the next example (cutting a tetrahedron along 3 edges), it seems that if an arrow $A$ pointed to a point $p$, then after a cut $\varphi$, $\varphi[A]$ consists of disjoint sets $X$ that each point towards elements of $\varphi[p]$, but that's a very specific guess based on just one example. Also I'm not sure it applies to this problem since the cuts on the sphere stop at the poles, whereas the point being tripled here is on several cuts.
[image: the tetrahedron cutting from the video]

Anyway, it seems like the analogous thing for the sphere would be:
[image: a different sphere cutting than the one in the video]

What's happening here? Did the arrows always point in the same direction? Or did something weird happen during the cut or distortion? I just can't imagine how to deform the square in the video back into the sphere we started with.

Comment: The sphere will decompose like the tetrahedron with all corners going to a single point.

Comment: That would solve my sphere issue! I don't quite see it with the tetrahedron though. Which corners of the tetrahedron map to a single point?

Comment: The three with the heavy black dot on them. They seam up along the three edges to a single point.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. I thought you were referring to the map I drew but I think you're going the opposite way. I agree about the tetrahedron and the yellow point"s" on the square, but the black point comes from the north pole and the red point comes from the south pole, no? Later in the video he calculates the Euler characteristic for this square, and he counts these same three distinct points on it, so it seems the black point is the image of the north pole and the red the image of the south, so I'm still confused why the images of the arrows don't point to the images of what they point to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might just be a small mistake in the video: [pi.math.cornell.edu/~mec/Winter2009/Victor/part2.htm](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Emec/Winter2009/Victor/part2.htm)